# How do I return to the default window arrangement in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: texniccenter

Somehow I accidentally hit a key sequence that altered the default window arrangement in TeXnicCenter, and I would like to "undo" this.  How?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! please explain your question better, for example what do you mean with default window arragement? Can you please show a screenshot with altered arrangement?

Comment: You can drag and drop them where you want them if that helps.

Comment: By "default" I mean what they were when I first installed the application.

Comment: You might try http://www.texniccenter.org/support/